# Do I need to have IDA Pro to use the BinDiff tool?

Tags: bin-diffing, tool-bindiff

I'm trying to learn how to use [BinDiff](https://www.zynamics.com/bindiff.html) tool, but I can't figure out how to open two binaries to do the comparison. While skimming through their manual, it seems like I need to have IDA Pro for that.

Can I use BinDiff without IDA Pro (say, with just IDA free)?

Comment: related: Alternatives to BinDiff https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/q/26196/3934 ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, this is now possible with Ghidra.

The latest version, BinDiff 6, has experimental support for the Ghidra disassembler. It ships with an extension that allows to export Ghidra disassembly into the .BinExport format needed for diffing.

### Required software

- BinDiff 6 from the [zynamics website](https://www.zynamics.com/software.html)
- A recent Java runtime (OpenJDK 11 or later)
- Ghidra 9.1.2 (https://ghidra-sre.org/releaseNotes_9.1.2.html)

### Installing the Ghidra Extension

After installing BinDiff, locate the "BinExport" extension in your installation folder.

The defaults are

- Windows: `C:\Program Files\BinDiff\extra\ghidra`
- Linux: `/opt/bindiff/extra/ghidra`
- macOS: `/Applications/BinDiff/Extra/Ghidra`

If you have located the `ghidra_BinExport.zip` file, the extension can be installed like any other Ghidra extension:

1. Start Ghidra, then select `File`|`Install Extensions...`.
2. Click the `+` button to `Add extension`.
3. In the `Select Extension` dialog, navigate to the directory containing
   `ghidra_BinExport.zip`.
4. Select the .zip file and click `OK`
5. Click `OK` to confirm and again to dismiss the restart message. Then restart
   Ghidra.

### Usage

This version of the Java based exporter for Ghidra has the following features
compared to the native C++ version for IDA Pro:

```
|                                         | Ghidra | IDA |
| --------------------------------------- | ------ | --- |
| Protocol Buffer based full export       |    ✓¹  |  ✓  |
| Statistics text file                    |    -   |  ✓  |
| Text format for debugging               |    -   |  ✓  |
| BinNavi export into PostgreSQL database |    -   |  ✓  |

¹ No operand trees
```

#### Verifying the installation version

1. In Ghidra, select `File`|`Install Extensions...`.
2. Verify that `BinExport` is listed and has the correct `Install Path`

#### Invocation

1. In Ghidra, open a project or create a new one.
2. If not already done, open the binary to export in the Code Browser tool and
   run Ghidra's initial analysis. You may want to enable the "aggressive
   instruction finder" option to get better coverage in the export.
3. In the project view, right-click the binary to export and select `Export...`
4. From the drop-down list, select `Binary BinExport (v2) for BinDiff`
5. Select a path for the output file. This can be the original filename, as
   `.BinExport` will be appended.
6. Click `OK`.

#### BinDiff Exported Files

Exported files can now be diffed and the results displayed in its UI:

1. Export two binaries following the instructions above. The
   following steps assume `primary.BinExport` and `secondary.BinExport`.
2. From the command-line, run the BinDiff engine with

   ```
   bindiff primary.BinExport secondary.BinExport
   ```

   This will create a file `primary_vs_secondary.BinDiff` in the current
   directory. The `bindiff` command should be in your system path.
3. Launch the BinDiff UI, either via `bindiff --ui` or using the launcher for
   your operating system.
4. Create a new workspace or open an existing one.
5. Select `Diffs`|`Add Existing Diff...`.
6. Under `Choose Diff`, select the `primary_vs_secondary.BinDiff` created in
   step 2.
7. Click `OK`, followed by `Add`. The diff is now shown in the tree view on the
   left and can be opened by double-clicking it.
8. Use BinDiff normally to display the call graph or flow graphs of matched
   functions.

### Open Source

Finally, the BinExport extension (and also the IDA Pro plugin) is open source and available [on GitHub](https://github.com/google/binexport). The `v11` tag corresponds to BinDiff 6.

Answer (score 3):

Bindiff can be a plugin in IDA or a standalone, but you still need the IDA database to compare binaries.

[image]

Comment: I doubt it will be able to open an .idb without IDA installed

Comment: @ismael_akez: can I generate a database file w/o IDA?

Comment: If you select an .idb or .i64, the UI will first launch IDA Pro and use BinExport to export he database.