# Alternative to BinDiff that works on Linux x86_64 binaries (and preferably does not require IDA Pro)

Tags: binary-analysis, bin-diffing, tool-bindiff

Is there alternative to
https://www.zynamics.com/bindiff.html
that works for Linux x86_64 binaries, works on Linux, (and preferably does not require IDA Pro, however if needed it seems that IDA can run on Linux so it may be fine)?

Comment: Related: BinDiff works with Ghidra https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/q/22372/3934

Answer (score 1):

VBinDiff at http://www.cjmweb.net/vbindiff/

---

Below is the same message as above. But with details if you're interested in those.

VBinDiff (Visual Binary Diff) code at https://github.com/madsen/vbindiff

VBinDiff displays files in hexadecimal and ASCII (or EBCDIC). It can also display two files at once, and highlight the differences between them.

VBinDiff is CLI only though (Command Line Interface)